# Как распознать знак ? в django url с помощью regex

Tags: python, django

По заданию необходимо сделать маршут который будет иметь следующий вид .../?city=...
Решил применить регулярные выражения но с толкнулся с проблемой, что приложение не распознает данный машрут из-за знака "?", экранировал его с помощью обратного слеша "?" но это не помогает как и взятие знака в квадратные скобки

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'\?city=([\w]+)/$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

terminal:

```
[08/Jan/2023 11:08:57] "GET /weather/?city=test/ HTTP/1.1" 404 2296
```

Если убрать "?" то маршрут работает корректно

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'city=([\w]+)/$', views.index, name='index')
]

[08/Jan/2023 11:24:21] "GET /weather/city=test/ HTTP/1.1" 200 134
```

Подскажите пожалуста, что я упустил...

Comment: Не очень разбираюсь конкретно в django, но знак вопроса в url значит начало списка параметров. Пример с поисковиком: `.../search?q=cats`. Возможно стоит просто принимать параметры в метод, и там уже их проверять? Т.е. сделать маппинг на /weather/.

Comment: Знак ? является техническим, разделяющим path и query string, поэтому его в принципе нигде нет